# Syntax error with emulating "create user if not exists"

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL does not allow you to specify an `if not exists` clause in a `create user` statement (despite the fact that `create table` and `create procedure` do support this). There was a feature request for this in 2005 but the MySQL devs have done sod all about it, so it's probably not going to happen anytime soon:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15287

I'm trying to emulate this functionality with the following statement:

```
if (select ifnull((select 1
                     from mysql.user
                    where User = 'recuser'
                      and Host = '%'), 0) = 0) then
  create user 'recuser'@'%' identified by password 'blah';
end if;
```

but MySQL complains about the syntax in the `if` statement - I can't see anything wrong with it, hopefully someone else can point out what the issue is.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

MySQL supports flow control constructs within stored procedures only.

Comment: ... and it doesn't have system stored procedures to add/remove users, and you can't `prepare` a `create user` statement because it's not supported. Another reason to "love" MySQL I guess.

Comment: You told him something he essentially already knows, instead of helping fix his problem...

Answer (score 10):

Denis answered your precise question, but there are other ways around your problem: see my answer to [mysql create user only when the user doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528393/mysql-create-user-only-when-the-user-doesnt-exist/5415585#5415585) (where there is also an example of a similar stored procedure as well)