# How to generically/dynamically create/drop users

Tags: mysql, database, missing-features

(Related to, but separate from [Syntax error with emulating "create user if not exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502885/syntax-error-with-emulating-create-user-if-not-exists).)

Is it possible to achieve the functionality of generically/dynamically adding a user (i.e. emulating the `sp_adduser` system procedure included with other DBMSs) in MySQL?

MySQL doesn't support the following `if [not] exists` syntax, see http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15287:

```
create user if not exists 'foo'@'%' identified by password 'bar';
```

It also doesn't support this:

```
drop procedure if exists create_user_if_not_exists;

delimiter ||

create procedure create_user_if_not_exists
               ( sUser     varchar(60),
                 sHost     varchar(16),
                 sPassword varchar(255) )
begin

-- ensure user does not yet exist
if (select ifnull((select 1
                     from mysql.user
                    where User = sUser
                      and Host = sHost), 0) = 0) then
  set @createUserText = concat('create user ''', sUser, '''@''', sHost, ''' identified by ''', sPassword, ''';');

  prepare createUserStatement FROM @createUserText;
  execute createUserStatement;
  deallocate prepare createUserStatement;
end if;

end ||

delimiter ;
```

because if you try to call said procedure:

```
call create_user_if_not_exists ( 'foo', '%', 'bar' );
```

you get the lovely message:

`This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`

The following works, but obviously is not particularly reusable:

```
drop procedure if exists create_user_if_not_exists;

delimiter ||

create procedure create_user_if_not_exists
               (  )
begin

if (select ifnull((select 1
                     from mysql.user
                    where User = 'foo'
                      and Host = '%'), 0) = 0) then
  create user 'foo'@'%' identified by password 'bar';
end if;

end ||

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh sorry i've just twigged you are talking about db users. not application users.

You might like the `INSERT INTO ...... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ......=VALUE(.....)` statement.

I use that in my general saving object method, using this i don't have to care if the user exists or not it'll be in there (and up-to-date) after i commit.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up going with. Doesn't feel particularly clean though...