# mysql create user only when the user doesn't exist

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to execute a `CREATE USER` statement, but only when the user doesn't already exist.
What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502885/syntax-error-with-emulating-create-user-if-not-exists

Comment: What is wrong for using `GRANT`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you're creating a user, you need to create a grant too. The grant implicitly creates a user if it doesn't exist (which is why you are encouraged to include the password when creating a grant, just in case they don't exist). see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

So an option is to just create the grant (with the password) and the user is implicitly created.

E.g:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON db_name.* 
TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' 
WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Simple and straightforward approach.

Comment: @iMysak have you tested this in 5.5 / 5.6 and it's not working - that would be odd, as I haven't found a note that this has been dropped (in fact doc seem to imply implicit creation - check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html)

Comment: in my case I needed to enable mode_no_auto_create_user http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_create_user  which is was enabled by default in old versions, but are disabled by default in new (5.5, 5.6).

Comment: Oh, ok - I think that setting only comes to force if you don't supply an authentication clause, ie.  `"IDENTIFIED BY 'password'"`

Comment: When I did this, here is the resonse I got:

`0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1287 Using GRANT for creating new user is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Create new user with CREATE USER statement.` !?

Comment: @Leonmax yes - looks like this has been recently deprecated in favour of  new syntax `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS` see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html (deprecation) and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html (if not exists)

Comment: Thanks @TimDiggins, I think maybe it's because my WorkBench is outdated, it prompt that create user if not exists is an syntax error...

Answer (score 2):

You can select from the "user" table on the default mysql database. Like this:

```
select *
from user
where User = 'username'
```

If no results are returned, create a new user.

Comment: The problem with that is that by the time your 'create' command is issued, the user may have been created after all. The risk of that happening is far from vanishingly small, if you are creating a web application that suddenly becomes popular.